# Safer version of quantum suicide?

Tags: quantum-interpretations

Quantum suicide imagines a gun which will shoot a person in a box, and this gun is rigged up to the release of radioactive decay which has a quantum probability of 50% chance of decaying or not decaying. If the radioactove particle decays  the man is shot. However after 100 times of doing this the gun is never fired, and this allows him to distinguish between the many worlds and copenhagen interpretation because only the version of you who lived can know that you lived.

Now Imagine if quantum suicide is performed, but the versions of the people who died are found within seconds, and are somehow resuscitated back to life(this is obviously highly unlikely but this is being used to prove a point). Now that these people have been brought back to life would that now invalidate the conclusion that the person who had survived the experiment for 100 clicks. The answer is no because the conclusions could still be drawn from that particular moment when every other version of him was dead(even though they were brought back to life).

Now because the conclusions of quantum suicide can be drawn from particular moments and people dont have to actually die, a safer version could be constructed.  Imagine quantum suicide but instead of the person being killed the person is put to sleep for an hour. Now one could argue that this couldn't work because eventually everyone would wake up, however in that moment the person would be able to know that he was the only one who was able to know that he is conscious because he is awake , and thus when the other versions wake up that person is still able to keep that knowledge from that moment in which the other versions of him were unconscious, and therefore be able to distinguish between MWI and copenhagen interpretation.

Would this work conceptually?

Comment: "and this allows him to distinguish between the many worlds and copenhagen interpretation" : please reconsider the logic of that statement - no it wouldn't.

Comment: Can you elaborate an experimental set-up reflecting what you have in mind? Some concepts may seeem precise enough until one tries and implement them in real physical systems. Like, here, the idea of "distinguishing". What actual experimental operation could perfom the "distinguishing" step?

Comment: Replacing sleep with death seems both valid and more practical, but there's a statistical fallacy implicit in the whole premise. An unlikely outcome doesn't prove anything: how can the person distinguish between MWI and simple random luck?

Comment: But that applies to not just this experiment, but to the original quantum suicide experiment right?

Comment: It's also about probability, its not that you have verified MWI it is that MWI is probably correct.

Comment: Yes, it's the flaw in the original experiment. The [flawed] assumption is that if something *extremely* unlikely actually happens (i.e. person survives at odds of 1 in 2^100), it can't be just random luck. Unfortunately, the laws of probability suggest otherwise. In fact, the thought experiment is redundant, since the logic behind it could simply be applied to the extreme unlikelihood of all the atoms being arranged to make you *you* - i.e. you improbably exist, therefore there must be other worlds where you don't exist, hence MWI proven.

Comment: But I like your variation. I was thinking about how it might be simplified: so, instead of a series of 100 "clicks" (whether lethal or sedative), why not a single trigger for the sedative but with very low probability that it's not administered (e.g. dose withheld if a beta decay detected within certain timeframe from a given quantity of Te130 atoms)? If the mechanism works and the person isn't sedated, they would know they're the only conscious "self" out of the 2^100 other "selves"...

Comment: Thank you I am hoping on publishing this any advice?